# File.createNewFile(): How to handle "unreported exception" error?

Tags: java, exception, io, compiler-errors

I'm new to the world of programming. I am on my 6th class and we were tasked to create a new file using an instance of File. I'm getting an io exception when compiling. I searched online but I can't seem to find an explanation I can understand about the issue.

Please bear with me but my code is:

```
import java.io.File;
public class TestFile{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File myArchive = new File("MyDocument.txt");
    boolean x = myArchive.createNewFile();
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

As I understand `createNewFile()` will provide a `true` value if the file is created, but I keep getting the following message.

> TestFile.java:5: error: unreported exception IOException; must be
>   caught or decl ared to be thrown
>       boolean x = myArchive.createNewFile();
>                                          ^ 1 error

From what I gathered online, there's an exception that needs to be caught. The instructor didn't advise of how to handle an exception on the code or anything to do with the commands `try` or `catch`.

Thank you very much for you assistance. If I'm not complying with any of the forums' guidelines, please let me know, this is my first post and again I'm fairly new to programing.

Comment: You need to wrap `myArchive.createNewFile();` within a `try..catch` block (or add a `throws` clause to the method signature). If your instructor didn't explain, this is a good time to learn it

Comment: This is a good place to start https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: I would question your instructor on why they gave an assignment that is impossible to complete without further instruction. :)

Comment: Also, welcome to StackOverflow! You did just fine for a first question, but do read the [ask] article as it provides invaluable information on how to get the best help in the future!

Comment: I've noted, your question was down-graded by someone for a moment, which is a kinda nasty attitude towards beginners. Some people may be too arrogant here, and think that StackOverflow is only for "professionals" like them, and attempt to sink down what seems obvious to them. Be it as it may, you asked a very legitimate question. And stackoverflow is a treasure of knowledge. Info here ranges from very basic to rocket-science. You post is good, well explained and legitimate. Bon courage! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `java` you will get many `Exceptions` and you have to handle It using `try..catch` block.

```
try{  
//code that may throw exception  
}catch(Exception_class_Name ref){}
```

Additionally you have to define `boolean x`  outside the try block and should be initialized to some value *(either true or false)* .

Try this code:-

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File myArchive = new File("MyDocument.txt");
    boolean x = true;
    try {
      x = myArchive.createNewFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
     System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

**Output:-**

```
true
```

Comment: I guess, it's better to initialize it to **false**, because if you initialize it to **true**,  and should the operation generate an exception, then it will stay and signal a "false" **true**, due to a failure to fulfil the try part.

Answer (score 1):

Just an intro to try-catch and what's it for:

Some operations may generate an error, which may even not be a mistake of the programmer, but may happen due to unforeseen circumstances.

For example, you want create a file, but at this moment, the file destination may become absent (e.g., a usb stick is taken out), or the disc may be full, or it may be an impossible filename (provided by another user through the keyboard, containing "forbidden" characters), or permission may not be given (e.g. in Android, when your phone asks for permissions to write files, you may grant it, or you may refuse to grant it for security's sake).

For such cases, Java provides you with an opportunity to try the error-prone code, and then catch the error. If an error happens, you don't want your app to crash. You want it to continue continue working, so you may warn the user on the screen that the file operation failed, and provide alternative actions.

So, basically, you do the following

```
 try{

   // place a risky part of code here
   // like, creating a file

 } catch (Exception error)
 {
     // This part will be executed only if there is an error
     // in this part, you can change the wrong file name
     // or tell the user that the disc is not available
     // just do something about the error.
     // If an error does not occur, then this part will not be executed.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        boolean x = myArchive.createNewFile();
        System.out.println(x);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The try block contains set of statements where an exception can occur. A try block is always followed by a catch block, which handles the exception that occurs in associated try block